Alexandria by Islam Issa--Did Artistotle know Latin or Hebrew?
I started reading the book Alexandria by Islam Issa, which is a history of the City of Alexandria, Egypt.  However, early on, there was one detail that seemed really off, and I wanted to get feedback on whether the following are true or plausible.  Specifically, the books claims that Aristotle taught Alexander Latin and Hebrew.  Neither of these seem plausible to me that Aristotle would even know these languages.  Rome had no territorial extent at the time and so Latin was an exceedingly minor language then.  Similarly, Hebrew was only used in a very small area, in a place fairly disconnected from Macedon and Greece.  Is this accurate?
I have looked at connections between Jewish and Greek philosophy, and while these are significant, they occur after Alexander and did not exist prior.

Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)

What research have you done to determine that it's unlikely for Aristotle to know Hebrew and Latin? He was a polymath and linguistics was one of his areas of interest. From my brief research there also appears to be a link between ancient Jewish and Greek traditions of philosophy, making that language a useful one to know.

@SPavel please see my revisions above.  I have looked at connections between Jewish and Greek philosophy, and while these are significant. they occur after Alexander and did not exist prior.

Note that it was a French Poet who suggested that Aristotle taught Latin The (unnamed) French poet was writing in the middle Ages.

@MCW, thanks, that's interesting.  The quote you give sounds like the source the author was using (although the book has no direct source given).  That actually tells me a lot about the book (specifically, that the author is comfortable using literary sources as historical facts), so thanks!

There is no evidence of Aristotle knowing any other language except the Greek language.  Latin would emerge as an international language at the beginning of The Pax Romana.....300 years AFTER Aristotle's death.  With regard to Hebrew, it was perhaps in the city of Alexandria whereby the Hebrew language became more internationalized-(or had gone beyond the borders of the Middle East).  While Aristotle was alive when Alexandria was founded in 331 BC/BCE, the city's famous Library-(and the vast Foreign Literatures it began to compile), did not come into being until 50 years AFTER his death.

Related: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/16473/61899 Aristotle might have been influenced by Jews (particularly their philosophy, expressed in he Old Testament and other writings), and he definitely encountered them - at least during the Alexander conquests in the Levant.

Another useful article: https://www.persee.fr/doc/rjuiv_0484-8616_1926_num_82_163_5501 If Aristotle knew Hebrew and was interested by Jewish Philosophy, it was likely in the process of the Alexander's conquests, not while tutoring him.

To my knowledge, a couple of Church Fathers have claimed that Plato met Jeremiah in Egypt (Ambrose, Augustine), and several Medieval Jewish philosophers and rabbis have claimed that Greek philosophers such as Plato, Socrates and Aristotle knew the last of the Biblical prophets, and even studied under them and/or debated them. Perhaps this is where the idea that Aristotle knew Hebrew stems from.

There is no historical or archeological evidence of Aristotle ever traveling to the Levant or outside the greater Greek world.  Aristotle's social contacts and interactions were exclusively with fellow Greeks....primarily in the city of Athens where he spent much of his intellectual life studying with, researching and teaching....fellow Greeks. Any of Aristotle's so-called encounters or interactions with non-Hellenic peoples is rooted in historical mythology and exaggerated speculation.

Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/87186/aristotle-learning-torah and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/104467/sources-for-greek-philosophy-being-influenced-by-judaism (Not the same Alex as above.)
